# Check when all dicom files of a study have sent

Tags: dicom, dcm4che

I have implemented my DICOM listener with a modified version of Storage Service (using as base dcmrcv tool) which implements the AssociationListener interface so i can monitor DICOM file send requests.

However i would like to know also WHEN all DICOM send requests for a whole study has sent! In other words to know which is the last DICOM file send request in a study!

Is that possible?

How am i going to route some processing on the DICOM sent files (just stored in file system) if i do not know when the whole study have sent?

any ideas?

Comment: Refer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38279743/5779732

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is “not possible”. There is no DICOM command or message attribute to indicate all images of a study are sent. Typically, SCU uses one association to send a study and associate release request could be the indication you are looking for.  However, an SCU may send different series of a study at different time. Such process will use separate association for each series. As for example, an imaging modality capturing images using different patient positions.

Also note that some SCU may try to establish multiple concurrent associations to send a study and as an SCP you have control over that by not accepting multiple associations from same AE.

Comment: SCU *sometimes* instead uses one association per object stored, but you're right "not possible".